# Redirect bash output called from batch file to console

Tags: bash, batch-file, msys

I have a batch file (build.bat) which calls a bash script (makelibs.sh). The bash script contains several commands which build 20 libraries from source.

If I run makelibs.sh from MSYS, I get continuous output. If I call it from the batch file, then I see the full output only at the end of every single command.

This makes it difficult to assess the current status of the process.

Is it possible to redirect the output of makelibs.sh in order to get a continuous feedback on the execution?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a batch file (build.bat) which calls a bash script (makelibs.sh)

I strongly advise against doing this. You are calling a script with a script, when you could simply open up Bash and put

```
makelibs.sh
```

However if you insist on doing this then perhaps [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) would work

```
start bash.exe makelibs.sh
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.cygwin)

Comment: Yes, I absolutely need to do it. The problem is that I would need also the output in the calling Window...